# EditText with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I know this has been introduced many times before but I cannot get it to work. The search filtering function doesn't seem to work properly with my `ListView`. Can anyone help me understand what's wrong in my code? Results are pulled fine from my DB but not filtered even after I enter text in my `EditText` field. I've tried to test the `EditText` on key changes with the Watcher and it works fine except for my list filtering.

Much Appreciated.

```
public class Interface extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

MyDbHelper mHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDb;
Cursor mCursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter, madapter;
ListView mList;
EditText returnsearch;
int textlength = 0;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "hohom";
public static final String COL_SanID = "SandIdc";
public static final String COL_SanTitle = "SandTitleC";
public static final String COL_SanCat = "SandCatC";
public static final String COL_SanReadyin = "SandReadyinC";
public static final String COL_SandServing = "SandServingC";
public static final String COL_SandIngred = "SandIngredC";
public static final String COL_SandDirect = "SandDirectC";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipesearch);

    mHelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listlist);
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    returnsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchrecipe);

    Bundle extrass = getIntent().getExtras();

    mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String Type = extrass.getString("CategoryType");

    String[] columns = new String[] {

    "_id", COL_SanID, COL_SanTitle, COL_SanCat, COL_SanReadyin,
            COL_SandServing, COL_SandIngred, COL_SandDirect };

    mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanCat + "=" + "?",
            new String[] { Type }, null, null, null);

    final String[] headers = new String[] { MyDbHelper.COL_SanTitle,
            MyDbHelper.COL_SanReadyin, MyDbHelper.COL_SandServing };

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listtype, mCursor,
            headers, new int[] { R.id.listmaintitle, R.id.listreadyin,
                    R.id.listserving });

    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    returnsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v)

{

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    Intent b = new Intent(Interface.this, Recipe.class);

    String rowId = mCursor.getString(0);
    String Title = mCursor.getString(2);
    String Category = mCursor.getString(3);
    String Readyin = mCursor.getString(4);
    String Serving = mCursor.getString(5);
    String Ingredients = mCursor.getString(6);
    String Directions = mCursor.getString(7);

    b.putExtra("Title", Title);
    b.putExtra("Category", Category);
    b.putExtra("Readyin", Readyin);
    b.putExtra("Serving", Serving);
    b.putExtra("Ingredients", Ingredients);
    b.putExtra("Directions", Directions);

    startActivity(b);

}

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build an AutoCompleteTextView but with an EditText and a ListView?

Comment: No i just want to build a listview that contains items pulled from the DB based on Category and i can limit the number of the recipes based on a EditText search. For Example : when the user enters Burger so all the items starting with Burger appears in the listview. Many Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I suggest adding a `FilterQueryProvider` to your SimpleCursorAdapter, this will tell the ListView how it should update.

Comment: Can you give me an example how can i do this? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(
    new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanCat + " = ? AND " + COL_SandIngred + " = ?", new String[] { Type, "%" + constraint + "%" }, null, null, null);
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit**

I added the keyword return so it might compile, sorry.  Anyway if the user enters "pickles" this should display all the sandwiches that contain pickles.

Comment: Thanks Sam for your answer. I'm trying now to implement this. But i just need to be sure if this will be implemented under the Watcher method ? Thanks!

Comment: Tried now with a simple query and it did get some results sorted by category only (it just for testing) but i realized that when i try to enter any letter in the edittext all results disappear and if i write the desired word (all the word) correctly the filtered items appears. How can i eliminate this? I want all items appears until the users finish the word (if there are matches for sure). Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, what if you ignore the FilterQueryProvider and try updating `mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanCat + "=" + "?",
            new String[] { s.toString() }, null, null, null);` in your afterTextChanged function? I have never used a text listener though...

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working. doesn't feel anything written in the edittext.

Comment: Could you set `mList`'s adapter to null in beforeTextChanged() and call `mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);` when you done typing in afterTextChanged() ?

Comment: I just read how a text watcher works... You could disable mAdapter when it receives focus in an onFocusChangeListener(), but I'm not sure when to enable mAdapter again. Perhaps adding a button is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Sam for your digging in , Much Appreciated ! What i need to implement is similar to the EditText in the Contacts . whenever you type on it,  it limits the search results on the listview based on that text.

Comment: Wait, I think I mis-read your comment.  Try `mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanCat + " LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + constraint + "%" }, null, null, null);` inside your FilterQueryProvider.

Comment: Wow It's working perfectly But when setting one condition only like : mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanTitle + " LIKE ?", new String[] { "%" + constraint + "%" }, null, null, null);

Comment: If i want also to limit the search by the Type which is passed by the previous Intent like 

return mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanCat
        + " = ? AND " + COL_SanTitle + " = ?", new String[] { Type , "%" + constraint
        + "%" }, null, null, null);

Comment: In this case it doesn't show correctly like the first one do.

Comment: At this point, you should research some SQL syntax. Look into the difference between `=` and `LIKE`; after you start getting results, then questions [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070508/sqlite-like-order-by-match-query) will help you organize the results. Good luck!

Comment: I fixed the issue and wanted to share it here so all people can learn from it. the confusion was on the ,Type, string that i wanted to filter with. I had to put it  between % % similar to the constraint  :))) so it should be like this. 

mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, COL_SanCat + " = ? AND " + COL_SanTitle + " = ?", new String[] { "%" + Type + "%" , "%" + constraint + "%" }, null, null, null);